# how to make sql to generate new number every day

Tags: sql

How to make sql to generate new number every day?
Like when report is being created, today it gives number 1, tomorrow number 2.

```
01.01.2017---1
01.01.2017---1
02.01.2017---2
02.01.2017---2
03.01.2017---3
03.01.2017---3
01.02.2017---32
01.05.2017---101
01.05.2017---101
10.05.2017---110
10.05.2017---110
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: `TO_CHAR(date, "yyyymmdd")` would do the trick in oracle.   The date changes, so why shouldn't that be your number?

Comment: `current_date - date '2017-01-01'`

Comment: `datediff(day,'starting date',getdate())` would work for SQL Server

Comment: `dayofyear(datecolumn)`?

Comment: Perhaps get the day number in the year from the date? For example in SQL server: `datepart(dayofyear, DATECOLUMN)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Select  DENSE_RANK ( )  OVER (order by edt) as agn, EDt 
from [dbo].[tempData]
```

Comment: **From Review**: This answer was flagged as **low quality**. While answers are always appreciated, it really helps to provide some information about how your code solves the problem at hand. Not everyone may be familiar with your exact coding logic, but may understand your general *approach* or *concept*. To help improve your answer, please provide some [**context surrounding it**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762), and see the help article on [**writing great answers**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for some tips on how to make your answers count :)